# Execute a method from a dynamically created instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a directory full of classes, and they basically all look like this:

```
class QEDestroy {

    void showSettings() {
        // Do Something Here
    }
}
```

I then have a class that will instantiate one of the classes based on an item that the user selects:

```
public class QESettings {

    public void GetSettings() {
        if (QEActions.actionInt >= 0) {
            string action = QEActions.actions[QEActions.actionInt];
            // Generate the class based on the action.
            // Run showSettings() within the class.
        }
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to instantiate the class; for example `QEDestroy`. From what I have read this is how the class is created:

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance("", "QE" + action);
```

If so, how do I run the method `showSettings()`?

Comment: usually all your classes would inherit from the same abstract class with showSettings() method defined, or all implement a known interface with the method. Then you'd cast your object to the base class or interface and then make the call.

Comment: Okay so I did that, now I get an error saying `ArgumentException: assemblyString cannot have zero length` I am not sure what to place in there for a Unity3 script...

Comment: You can try null instead of "", if it if these classes are in the executing assembly. Otherwise the name of the assembly is needed.

Comment: I found that I should do this: `ActionSettings settings = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("QE" + action)) as ActionSettings;` But then I get `ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.`..

Comment: Make sure Type.GetType("QE" + action) is actually returning a type. Remember that case matters.

Comment: Got it! The value of action was misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is often the correct one. Create an `interface`.

```
public interface QE
{
    void showSettings();
}
```

Then have different "versions" of `QE` that perform different tasks on the `showSettings()` function.

```
public class QE_Example
{
    public void override showSettings()
    {
        print("I am different.");
    }
}
```

Then when you instantiate in your `QESettings` class you do it like this:

```
public void GetSettings()
{
    if(QEActions.actionInt >= 0) 
    {
        ...
        QE q = new QE_Example();
        q.showSettings();
    }
}
```

---

This means you have actually stumbled upon a well known Design Pattern named [**Strategy Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

[image]

Comment: So, how do I initiate a class where the class name will be different? I could do a huge `if/else` or `switch` but that doesn't sound like a good Idea

Comment: You will need either if statements or an event that triggers which instant will be used.